# Socket.io reconnect problem on safari desktop

Tags: socket.io, safari, webrtc

I have an call app using webRTC API and using socket.io for signaling server. It work stable on Chrome, but on Safari 15.5,it has a problem that the socket.io does not automatically reconnect when a socket instance disconnect from server. Sometimes it show log that the socket connect failed because of time out.
I'm using socket.io 4.5.0 and ReactJs. Any idea to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: You may check https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/4263 and https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/4410 to see if they shed some light on yours.